# How to put 18 character text inside fa-fa icon ticket

Tags: css

How to put 18 character text inside fa-fa icon ticket. Icon should be slanted & text should be inside it. And a 18 character text (QWERTYUIOPQWERTYUI) would be inside the icon. How can I do it using css? This is the style I want to show:

[image: image description]

Comment: Have you any code to show us, what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

you can use **position:absolute** and **rotate 45 degrees** for your 18 character text.

```css
span {
  position:absolute;
  left:30px;
  top:45px;
  color:yellow;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  font-size:3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<i class="fa fa-ticket fa-5x"></i> <span>QWERTYUIOPQWERTYUI</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Of course, the font size of the text must be very small to fit in the ticket and you have to use the prefixes for webkit, mozilla, opera,... for transform.